# Python zip and itertools

Tags: python

Hello everyone ı want to merge two lists as you see in ds_out ı didn't find any way so did it with for loop but list_two len must be 3*of list_one  if ı type 5 element or 7 elements in list_two it gives index error how can fix it many thanks.

```
list_one = (1,2,3)
list_two = ("a","b","c","d","e","f")

ds_out = []
for i in list_one:
    ds_out.append(i)
    ds_out.append(list_two[i-1])
    ds_out.append(list_two[i+2])

print(ds_out)

ds_out = [1, 'a', 'd', 2, 'b', 'e', 3, 'c', 'f']
```

Comment: Those are not lists but tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an iterator from `list_two`, `zip` it with itself for each item in `list_one`, transpose it with another `zip` so that the groupings align with each item in `list_one` to `zip` together for output:

```
s = iter(list_two),
[i for k, v in zip(list_one, zip(*zip(*s * len(list_one)))) for i in (k, *v)]
```

This returns:

```
[1, 'a', 'd', 2, 'b', 'e', 3, 'c', 'f']
```

If items in `list_two` do not necessarily distribute evenly for items in `list_one`, you can use `itertools.zip_longest` instead of `zip` with a dummy `fillvalue` so that you can skip the missing values during output:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
list_one = (1,2,3)
list_two = ("a","b","c","d","e")
skip = object()
print([
    i
    for k, v in zip(
        list_one, zip(*zip_longest(*(iter(list_two),) * len(list_one), fillvalue=skip))
    )
    for i in (k, *v) if i is not skip
])
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 'a', 'd', 2, 'b', 'e', 3, 'c']
```

Comment: Thaks lot also this code works but as ı typed above list two must be 3,6,9 etc. if list has 8 element this code zip 6 element

Comment: I've updated my answer for such a scenario then.

Answer (score 1):

```
cycle1 = itertools.cycle(list_one) # repeat this sequence forever
result = {} # to hold our lists matching each entry in list_one
for one,two in zip(cycle1,list_two): 
    result.setdefault(one,[]).append(two)

ds_out = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[x,*result[x]] for x in list_one]))
```

I think  would give the correct result